How to solve PYTHONPATH error at System Environment Variables Editor and impotr numpy?
When I wrote these codes, the following error occurred.
import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\users\user\desktop\fullstack-api\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py:24
     23 try:
---> 24     from . import multiarray
     25 except ImportError as exc:

File c:\users\user\desktop\fullstack-api\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py:10
      9 import functools
---> 10 from . import overrides
     11 from . import _multiarray_umath

File c:\users\user\desktop\fullstack-api\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py:8
      7 from .._utils._inspect import getargspec
----> 8 from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
      9     add_docstring,  _get_implementing_args, _ArrayFunctionDispatcher)
     12 ARRAY_FUNCTIONS = set()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\users\user\desktop\fullstack-api\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:144
    143 try:
--> 144     from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
    145 except ImportError as e:

File c:\users\user\desktop\fullstack-api\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__config__.py:4
      3 from enum import Enum
----> 4 from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
      5     __cpu_features__,
      6     __cpu_baseline__,
      7     __cpu_dispatch__,
      8 )
     10 __all__ = ["show"]

File c:\users\user\desktop\fullstack-api\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py:50
     27     msg = """
     28 
     29 IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!
   (...)
     48 """ % (sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1], sys.executable,
     49         __version__, exc)
---> 50     raise ImportError(msg)
     51 finally:

ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\python.exe"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.26.4"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import numpy as np

File c:\users\user\desktop\fullstack-api\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:149
    145 except ImportError as e:
    146     msg = """Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
    147     its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
    148     your python interpreter from there."""
--> 149     raise ImportError(msg) from e
    151 __all__ = [
    152     'exceptions', 'ModuleDeprecationWarning', 'VisibleDeprecationWarning',
    153     'ComplexWarning', 'TooHardError', 'AxisError']
    155 # mapping of {name: (value, deprecation_msg)}

ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.


I've wrote the PYTHONPATH at System Environment Variables Editor before.
PTYHONPATH is "C:\Users\user\Desktop\fullstack-api\venv\Lib\site-packages"
So, after having the above error I edited PYTHONPATH at System Environment Variables Editor
PYTHONPATH is "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python"
Later, the code was executed normally.
So I wanted to check if the path of numpy was changed to PYTHONPATH, so I write "print(np)", but the path was taken from anaconda's own file path.
enter image description here
But if jupyter notebook is going to bring modules from anaconda's own folder anyway, I wonder why the error at first is that c:\users\user\desktop\fullstack-api\venv\lib\site-packages can't find modules in this path.
